# Javascript code to detect current page

Tags: javascript

Is there a javascript code that can detect what page my user is on and then add a class to a `ul` item?  I want to put my menu in my static HTML website in a separate file and then use PHP include to add it, but I want `class="current"` for the current page.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(window.location == 'myfixedurl')
{
    document.getElementById('menuList').className += 'current';
}
```

You probably want to tweak window.location so that it looks at relative paths, or absolute without hostname, etc.

Keep in mind if the user disables JavaScript they won't have the visual indicator of which page they're on.

If you have access to PHP why not do it in the server side code instead of client side?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably interested in `window.location` or `window.location.pathname`.

I would recommend to do this in PHP though if you're already using it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely ... Create a css class for the current state and then dynamically add the class to the ul element via JavaScript ...

```
/*css*/

#nav li.current  {
background-color:#ffffff;    

}     

/*Using JQuery*/

$('#nav li a').each(function(){

var path = window.location.href;
var loc = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
var url = $(this).attr('href');

if(url == loc){
$(this).parent().addClass('current');
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in PHP, but you can use something like window.location